# Send Details To Email After Validation

Tags: php, forms, validation

I have added the php codes for validation of information in the contact form.....but I don't know how to allow it to send the details after the validation....here are the codes...what codes should be added after the validation so that the details will be send to my email

```
    <?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$first_nameErr = $emailErr = $genderErr = $prefixErr = $messageErr = $last_nameErr =                       $confirm_emailErr = $ic_passportErr = $addressErr = $cityErr = $stateErr = $postal_codeErr = $mobile_numberErr = $licenceErr = $subjectErr = "";
$first_name = $email = $gender = $prefix = $message = $last_name = $confirm_email = $ic_passport = $address = $city = $state = $postal_code = $mobile_number = $licence = $subject = "";

  if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
  {
   if (empty($_POST["first_name"]))
  {$first_nameErr = "First name is required";}
  else
  {
  $first_name = test_input($_POST["first_name"]);
  // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
  if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$first_name))
   {
   $first_nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
      }
     }

    if (empty($_POST["last_name"]))
     {$last_nameErr = "Last name is required";}
    else
     {
    $last_name = test_input($_POST["last_name"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
     if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$last_name))
      {
       $last_nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
      }
      }

    if (empty($_POST["confirm_email"]))
    {$confirm_emailErr = "E-mail is required";}
  else
    {
    $confirm_email = test_input($_POST["confirm_email"]);
   // check if e-mail address syntax is valid
    if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$confirm_email))
      {
      $confirm_emailErr = "Invalid e-mail "; 
      }
    }

   if (empty($_POST["ic_passport"]))
     {$ic_passportErr = "Ic / Passport No. is required";}
    else
     {
       $ic_passport = test_input($_POST["ic_passport"]);
     // check if ic/passport is valid 
     if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$/",$ic_passport))
      {
       $ic_passportErr = "Invalid Ic / Passport No."; 
       }
      }

   if (empty($_POST["message"]))
    {$messageErr = "Please type your message on the space provided above";}
      else
     {$message = test_input($_POST["message"]);}

   if (empty($_POST["subject"]))
     {$subjectErr = "Subject is required";}
   else
    {$subject = test_input($_POST["subject"]);}

   if (empty($_POST["gender"]))
     {$genderErr = "Gender is required";}
   else
    {$gender = test_input($_POST["gender"]);}

  if (empty($_POST["address"]))
    {$addressErr = "Address is required";}
   else
    {$address = test_input($_POST["address"]);}

    if (empty($_POST["city"]))
    {$cityErr = "City is required";}
    else
    {$city = test_input($_POST["city"]);}

     if (empty($_POST["state"]))
     {$stateErr = "State is required";}
    else
     {$state = test_input($_POST["state"]);}

      if (empty($_POST["postal_code"]))
     {$postal_codeErr = "Postal Code is required";}
    else
      {$postal_code = test_input($_POST["postal_code"]);}

      if (empty($_POST["mobile_number"]))
     {$mobile_numberErr = "Mobile Number is required";}
   else
     {$mobile_number = test_input($_POST["mobile_number"]);}

    if (empty($_POST["licence"]))
    {$licenceErr = "Please choose the package you would like to enquire";}
     else
     {$licence = test_input($_POST["licence"]);}
 }

  function test_input($data)
 {
 $data = trim($data);
 $data = stripslashes($data);
 $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
 return $data;
 }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combine your errors in a variable or array 
After that, check if errors are empty in an `if()` statement 
if it comes true send your mail using `mail()` function. 

that will enable you to make sure all the mandatory fields are filled and validation is complete. Then it is ok to send the details in mail.

Answer (score 0):

Use the mail() function:

mail(to,subject,message,headers,parameters)

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mail.asp

Comment: No, don't use the mail() function. Use a proper system like http://swiftmailer.org/.

Comment: The mail() function is a perfectly good solution for sending simple one-off emails. I use it regularly for things like this with no adverse effects.

Comment: It's way too easy to turn yourself in a spambot if you're using `mail()` with user-provided input. Lots of pit-falls. A sane API like Swift provides is going to result with far fewer headaches down the road.